# how to read characters from a string and then associate them to a numeric value?

Tags: c++, oop, calendar

To input the date in the form of a string (12/JUNE/2017), and then obtain that month's calendar.
So how to associate JUNE with the number 6 (june is the 6th month in the calander.)

Comment: You need to *map* the string to the number. There are classes in the C++ standard library that can help you with that. Or you could just have a big `if ... else if...` chain to compare the strings.

Comment: Please add some code of what you already tried or have, so we can better help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a hash table ( hash map ) with key as month (string) and value as month number(int).
First use string.find() function to extract the month from input string, then take its value from map.